# Stochastic Analogue of Stokes Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes

Dynkin's formula can be thought of as the stochastic version of the Fundamental Theorem of calculus,
$$E^x[f(X_{\tau})]=f(x)+E^x\left[\int_0^{\tau}Af(X_u)du\right],$$
where $\tau$ is a first exit time and $A$ is the generator of the process $X_t$.
I'm wondering what the stochastic version of the Stokes theorem, say on a surface with boundary, should be?

Answer (score 5):

See, e.g., ["Integral of differential forms along the path of diffusion processes" by Ikeda and Manabe](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/15/3/15_3_827/_article). Perhaps the "Stokes theorem" in [Malliavin's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=F1YwCgAAQBAJ) is also of interest.